# Port forwarding external IP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I've configured port forwarding on my `Thomson TWG 870` router to forward ftp, ssh and http connections to my home server. Everything works great when the `External IP` address is set to 0.0.0.0. When i change it to my public WAN IP (assigned by my ISP) the forwarding stops working. Why is it like that?

Comment: Because the `External IP` limits port forwarding to the host identified by that particular IP address? Just guessing. Actually, I suggest you clarify whether `External IP` is a setting of the router's port forwarding functionality, whether you read the user's manual and where we can find it, which firmware version it runs, ans which forum posts didn't help you.

Comment: Did you have a look at the manual to check what it says in regards to that setting and what's supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, i've read the manual but there is nothing special about the External IP setting. Jest check it out yourself: http://setuprouter.com/router/thomson/twg-870/manuals.htm